# Meaning of "machte" in a conversation in a novel

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading a novel, and in a couple places I have read:

> »Oh«, machte er.

I know that "machte" is the preterite form of "machen," meaning "to make." However, I can't find a meaning of the word "machen" that has to do with vocalization. Is it used in this context because he is "making" an "oh" sound? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply yet another synonym for 'utter'. 'Er macht "oh"' == "He goes "oh!"'.

You can use it with real words, but more idiomatically it's used with onomatopoesy, like "Oh!" or "Au!" - or even of animals, who have only pseudo-words: 'Die Kuh macht "muh!"

Comment: Thank you! So it would also be correct to use with other sentences that are uttered, like "»Ja«, machte er"?

Comment: You *can* use it with real words, but more idiomatically it's used with onomatopoesy, like "Oh!" or "Au!" - or even of animals, who have *only* pseudo-words: 'Die Kuh macht "muh!"

Comment: @KilianFoth I moved your comment into your answer as it clarifies the usage quite a bit more. Please adjust, if you see this unfit.